# Output changes wildly with input voltage in photodiode circuit

Tags: amplifier, photodiode

I am currently analyzing a photodiode sensor input circuit (not designed by me, but schematics drawn from a commercial product). I am currently simulating the circuit on TINA TI. While experimenting with different input voltages, I noticed that the output *waveform* (output of second op-amp) changes a lot with the input voltage, while the output of first op-amp seems to be amplified more linearly.

Unfortunately my analog electronics knowledge is very limited, so I couldn't understand which concept of analog electronics is associated with this result. Phase response maybe? Or something more complicated?

Diagrams:

Circuit

[image]

50 mV pulse transient response

[image]

100 mV pulse transient response

[image]

Bode Plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as you have used the 1.8K resistor in second stage amplifier but in first stage it was 3.1k so as per the formula G=1+(Rf/Rin)

The gain for second stage is greater than the first stage.

Comment: But why the distortion in output signal when input is 50 mV?

Comment: for that can you measure the voltage after C3 capacitor?

Comment: There is "droop" because of the low-pass-nature (the DC blocking caps). Audio Power Amps will also do this, because of DC blocking (flutter and turntable rumble filters). In the 100mV input, your opamp may be hitting the rail.